Would Like To Print Source Code for all Forms and Modules in a VB6 project
I have a classic VB6 project which contains forms and modules. I would like to add a Sub procedure to one of the modules which will print to a file the source VB6 code in all the forms and modules in the project. I didn't know how to do this so I asked ChatGPT 4.0 to write the code for the Sub procedure. ChatGPT generated the code, and I was told to add a reference to "Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" to the project. I added the reference and ran the Sub procedure. The program stopped when it reached the line "Set vbProj = VBIDE.VBE.ActiveVBProject". "VBE" was highlighted and the error message was "Method or data member not found". Below is the Sub procedure. I would be grateful if someone could suggest a correction to get this to work. Thank you.
Public Sub ExportAllCode()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fileStream As Object
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Dim vbProj As Object
    Dim vbComps As Object
    Dim vbCompItem As Object
    Dim lineNum As Long
    Dim codeLine As String

    ' Create a FileSystemObject to handle the file operations
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Create or open the output file
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(App.Path & "\AllCode.txt", True)

    ' Get the VB Project
    Set vbProj = VBIDE.VBE.ActiveVBProject
    Set vbComps = vbProj.VBComponents

    ' Loop through all the components (Forms, Modules, Classes) in the project
    For Each vbComp In vbComps
        ' Write the component name to the file
        fileStream.WriteLine "Component: " & vbComp.Name
        fileStream.WriteLine String(50, "=")
        
        ' Write the code lines of the component to the file
        For lineNum = 1 To vbComp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
            codeLine = vbComp.CodeModule.Lines(lineNum, 1)
            fileStream.WriteLine codeLine
        Next lineNum
        
        ' Add a separator between components
        fileStream.WriteLine String(50, "=")
        fileStream.WriteLine
    Next vbComp

    ' Close the file
    fileStream.Close

    ' Clean up
    Set fileStream = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set vbComp = Nothing
    Set vbComps = Nothing
    Set vbProj = Nothing

    MsgBox "Code export complete. The file 'AllCode.txt' has been created in the application path.", vbInformation
End Sub


Chatgpt did you wrong. That is vba code for a Microsoft Office app. It's not going to work in vb6 as is, and I don't think there's any tricks you can do to make it work.

I will continue to look into it and I won't assume it's not going to work.  ChatGPT has written a lot of excellent VB6 code for me, but it does seem to get confused about differences between VB6 and VBA.

(1) I restate the requirements as follows: print all file contents in a directory. (2) Just process the file to be printed as a text file. (3) The program logic does not need to be executed in VB6  (4) so you can execute it in VBA in Excel or Word.

I know that the .frm files and .bas files in a VB6 project are text files. I can easily send them to a printer (after stripping out the code at the top of the .frm files that specifies the controls and their properties).  My interest is in understanding the VBE object, the ActiveVBProject property, the VBComponents object, and extensibility, and why the code above doesn't work.

Have a look at these two projects: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1539/Create-VB-Add-Ins and https://www.developer.com/microsoft/visual-basic/creating-a-visual-basic-6-add-in/

Thank you, Hel O'Ween.  The articles might have just what I'm looking for.

Check out corrected code on vbforums.com.

It looks like the link provided by @wqw is CurtisD asking the same question at another forum. This is definitely an XY Problem, as CurtisD states in the linked post, "... I would like to print the source code for the entire project once a week to preserve a history of the project." For that, use proper source control. There are free options like VisualSVN Server and many others. Why "re-invent the wheel" for source control in a sub-par way?
